# Cannot install linux dual boot with Windows 8

Tags: dual-boot, usb-installation

Every time I try to install from usb and it does not give me the option of Installation Type, it goes straight to the installation setup with no partition to choose from and crashes when I do anything on this screen. What am I doing wrong or not doing?

Comment: What buttons are you choosing?

Comment: What do you mean? I click the buttons to choose to install the updates while installing and the next menu it goes to asks to choose a partition but there isn't any to choose. Never gives me the option to install alongside windows 8. It skips that menu